# Simple reRender output panel

Tags: visualforce

Click this button should rerender my output panel and display the latest saved value - correct?

```
<apex:page standardController="Reject_Lead__c"  cache="false" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >  
       <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Reject_Lead__c.RL_LeadStatus__c}"/>
       </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!null}" rerender="thePanel" value="FIRE!"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `action` attribute on [apex:commandButton](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm) states:

> If an action isn't specified, the page simply refreshes

So all you need to do is remove `action="{!null}"` from your command button as shown below:

```
<apex:commandButton rerender="thePanel" value="FIRE!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this seems to be fine

```
rerender="thePanel"
```

your action function

```
action="{!null}"
```

looks very strange to me. Rerender is coupled to an actionFunction you should/must provide.

Do you have an action function in the controller? Does your code work?

Comment: I only want to trigger the refresh of the output panel. No save or updates, just surface the data stored

Comment: No problem, but you still need to provide an action function and it would  just return null. It goes like `public PageReference DoNothing() { return null; }`

Comment: Thanks Richard, I was trying to escape writing controller stuff. What I actually want to do is rerender a single row in my pageblocktable. But thats one for another day. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This works for checking rerender attribute of commandButton works with outputPanel or not :-

```
public class CustomController{
    public integer i;
    public CustomController() {i = 1;}
    public integer getI() {return i;}
    public void calculate() {i = i + 1;} 
}
```

VF page which uses above custom controller :-

```
<apex:page controller="CustomController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Increment" action="{!calculate}" rerender="Panel1"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="Panel1">
      <apex:outputText value="{!i}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```